# how to add JavaScript cookies consent alert disappear after time 3 minute

Tags: javascript

this is a working JavaScript cookies consent alert but this alert are not disappear without user click on accept button.

we need are cookies consent alert disappear after time 2 minute, when user are not click on accept button, how do this one ?

This code are work perfect and also add to codepen https://codepen.io/MrUmang/pen/oNYZLej

```
cookieLaw = {
  dId: "cookie-law-div",
  bId: "cookie-law-button",
  iId: "cookie-law-item",
  show: function(e) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(cookieLaw.iId)) return !1;
    var o = document.createElement("div"),
      i = document.createElement("p"),
      t = document.createElement("button");
    i.innerHTML = e.msg, t.id = cookieLaw.bId, t.innerHTML = e.ok, o.id = cookieLaw.dId, o.appendChild(t), o.appendChild(i), document.body.insertBefore(o, document.body.lastChild), t.addEventListener("click", cookieLaw.hide, !1)
  },
  hide: function() {
    document.getElementById(cookieLaw.dId).outerHTML = "", localStorage.setItem(cookieLaw.iId, "1")
  }
}, cookieLaw.show({
  msg: "We use cookies to give you the best possible experience. By continuing to visit our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our <a href='https://sarkari.in/cookie-policy/'>Find out more.</a>",
  ok: "Okay, thanks"
});
```

```css
#cookie-law-div {
  z-index: 10000000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3%;
  right: 2%;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgba(23,43,99,.4) 0 7px 28px;
}


#cookie-law-div a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#cookie-law-div a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

#cookie-law-div p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

#cookie-law-div button {
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
  top: 20px;
  align-self: center;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  opacity: .9;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
}

#cookie-law-div button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  #cookie-law-div {
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    max-width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }
#cookie-law-div p {padding-right: 75px;}
}
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` to call the hide function? If there's more to it, you may need to expand and clarify the question.

Comment: full code add here we need  disappear this banner after 2 minute of without user any action https://codepen.io/MrUmang/pen/oNYZLej

Answer (score -1):

Use [setTimeout and clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#timeouts). The code has been amended to use the two timeout functions.

The `timeout` property defines the number of seconds to wait before calling the `cookieLaw.hide` function.

The `timeoutId` property stores the id of the timeout so that it can be removed by the `clearTimeout` function call when `cookieLaw.hide` executes.

```js
cookieLaw = {
  dId: "cookie-law-div",
  bId: "cookie-law-button",
  iId: "cookie-law-item",
  timeout: 120,
  timeoutId: -1,
  show: function(e) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(cookieLaw.iId)) return !1;
    var o = document.createElement("div"),
      i = document.createElement("p"),
      t = document.createElement("button");
    i.innerHTML = e.msg, t.id = cookieLaw.bId, t.innerHTML = e.ok, o.id = cookieLaw.dId, o.appendChild(t), o.appendChild(i), document.body.insertBefore(o, document.body.lastChild), t.addEventListener("click", cookieLaw.hide, !1);
    cookieLaw.timeoutId = window.setTimeout(cookieLaw.hide, cookieLaw.timeout*1000);
  },
  hide: function() {
    document.getElementById(cookieLaw.dId).outerHTML = "", localStorage.setItem(cookieLaw.iId, "1");
    window.clearTimeout(cookieLaw.timeoutId);
  }
}, cookieLaw.show({
  msg: "We use cookies to give you the best possible experience. By continuing to visit our website, you agree to the use of cookies as described in our <a href='https://sarkari.in/cookie-policy/'>Find out more.</a>",
  ok: "Okay, thanks"
});
```

```css
#cookie-law-div {
  z-index: 10000000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 3%;
  right: 2%;
  padding: 5px 12px;
  max-width: 400px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: rgba(23,43,99,.4) 0 7px 28px;
}


#cookie-law-div a {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

#cookie-law-div a:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

#cookie-law-div p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #000;
  padding-right: 70px;
}

#cookie-law-div button {
  position: absolute;
  right: .5em;
  top: 20px;
  align-self: center;
  line-height: 33px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  opacity: .9;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 19px;
}

#cookie-law-div button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media (max-width:600px) {
  #cookie-law-div {
border-radius: 0;
font-size: 13px;
max-width: 100%;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
  }
#cookie-law-div p {padding-right: 75px;}
}
```